# AWS CLI on windows docker

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, asp.net-web-api, aws-cli, amazon-ecs

I am working on asp.net applications. The current plan is to setup CI pipeline in AWS with ECS. So basically I created 2 stages now.

**Scenario:**

I have an ASP.NET Web API application built on .NET Framework 4.6.2. I need to setup a containerized CI/CD pipeline using the AWS Code pipeline.

My initial focus to setup CI only which includes automating the source build, unit test and upload the build to ECR repository as a docker. This will be used in the next stage to deploy in ECS.

**Current Progress and Problem Description:**

Stage 1: Source
  This stage configured successfully with the GitHub webhook.

Stage 2: Build
  I used Microsoft docker ('mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk:4.7.2') as a build environment image.
This is working fine for build and unit testing.

Now I need to build the docker image and push to ECR repository. I created a repository and done the commands locally. I also enabled docker support in my application so docker-compose also there.

I am stopped here as I don't have any idea to continue...

My current build spec file consists of following;

```
    version: 0.2

env:
  variables:
    PROJECT: aspnetapp
    DOTNET_FRAMEWORK: 4.6.2
phases:
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - echo Logging in to Amazon ECR...
      - aws --version
      - $(aws ecr get-login --region $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION --no-include-email)
      - REPOSITORY_URI=727003307347.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/ecr-repo-axiapp-cloud
      - COMMIT_HASH=$(echo $CODEBUILD_RESOLVED_SOURCE_VERSION | cut -c 1-7)
      - IMAGE_TAG=aspnetapi
  build:
    commands:
      - echo Build started on `date`
      - nuget restore
      - msbuild $env:PROJECT.sln /p:TargetFrameworkVersion=v$env:DOTNET_FRAMEWORK /p:Configuration=Release /p:DeployIisAppPath="Default Web Site" /p:PackageAsSingleFile=false /p:OutDir=C:\codebuild\artifacts\ 
  post_build:
    commands:
      - echo Build completed on `date`
      - echo Pushing the Docker images...
      - docker push $REPOSITORY_URI:latest
      - docker push $REPOSITORY_URI:$IMAGE_TAG
artifacts:
  files:
    - '**/*'
  base-directory: C:\codebuild\artifacts\
```

While running, I got an error on `aws --version`. From this, I can understand that we need to install AWS CLI on the build server. For that, I am creating a custom docker. I got an articles and following the same for this.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/extending-aws-codebuild-with-custom-build-environments-for-the-net-framework/

From the article, I have the following DockerFile

```
    # escape=`

FROM microsoft/dotnet-framework:4.7.2-runtime

SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';"]

#Install NuGet CLI
ENV NUGET_VERSION 4.4.1
RUN New-Item -Type Directory $Env:ProgramFiles\NuGet; `
    Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing https://dist.nuget.org/win-x86-commandline/v$Env:NUGET_VERSION/nuget.exe -OutFile $Env:ProgramFiles\NuGet\nuget.exe

#Install AWS CLI
RUN Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing https://s3.amazonaws.com/aws-cli/AWSCLI64PY3.msi -OutFile AWSCLI64PY3.msi

# Install VS Test Agent
RUN Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/12210068/8a386d27295953ee79281fd1f1832e2d/vs_TestAgent.exe -OutFile vs_TestAgent.exe; `
    Start-Process vs_TestAgent.exe -ArgumentList '--quiet', '--norestart', '--nocache' -NoNewWindow -Wait; `
    Remove-Item -Force vs_TestAgent.exe; `
# Install VS Build Tools
    Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/12210059/e64d79b40219aea618ce2fe10ebd5f0d/vs_BuildTools.exe -OutFile vs_BuildTools.exe; `
    # Installer won't detect DOTNET_SKIP_FIRST_TIME_EXPERIENCE if ENV is used, must use setx /M
    setx /M DOTNET_SKIP_FIRST_TIME_EXPERIENCE 1; `
    Start-Process vs_BuildTools.exe -ArgumentList '--add', 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.MSBuildTools', '--add', 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetCoreBuildTools', '--add', 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.WebBuildTools;includeRecommended', '--quiet', '--norestart', '--nocache' -NoNewWindow -Wait; `
    Remove-Item -Force vs_buildtools.exe; `
    Remove-Item -Force -Recurse \"${Env:ProgramFiles(x86)}\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\"; `
    Remove-Item -Force -Recurse ${Env:TEMP}\*; `
    Remove-Item -Force -Recurse \"${Env:ProgramData}\Package Cache\"

# Set PATH in one layer to keep image size down.
RUN setx /M PATH $(${Env:PATH} `
    + \";${Env:ProgramFiles}\NuGet\" `
    + \";${Env:ProgramFiles(x86)}\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\TestAgent\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\" `
    + \";${Env:ProgramFiles(x86)}\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\")

# Install Targeting Packs
RUN @('4.0', '4.5.2', '4.6.2', '4.7.2') `
    | %{ `
        Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing https://dotnetbinaries.blob.core.windows.net/referenceassemblies/v${_}.zip -OutFile referenceassemblies.zip; `
        Expand-Archive -Force referenceassemblies.zip -DestinationPath \"${Env:ProgramFiles(x86)}\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\"; `
        Remove-Item -Force referenceassemblies.zip; `
    }
```

I tried to download AWS CLI using the command.

1. If my understanding right, please help me to update the Dockerfile to install AWS CLI.
2. So same way shall I need to install docker for windows also in the build server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done this. Please find the updated docker file

```
    # escape=`

FROM microsoft/dotnet-framework:4.7.2-runtime

SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';"]
#Install NuGet CLI
ENV NUGET_VERSION 4.4.1
RUN New-Item -Type Directory $Env:ProgramFiles\NuGet; `
    Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing https://dist.nuget.org/win-x86-commandline/v$Env:NUGET_VERSION/nuget.exe -OutFile $Env:ProgramFiles\NuGet\nuget.exe

#Install AWS CLI
RUN Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing https://s3.amazonaws.com/aws-cli/AWSCLI64PY3.msi -OutFile AWSCLI64PY3.msi; `
    Start-Process "msiexec.exe"  -ArgumentList '/i', 'AWSCLI64PY3.msi', '/qn', '/norestart' -Wait -NoNewWindow; `
    Remove-Item -Force AWSCLI64PY3.msi; `


# Install VS Test Agent
    Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/12210068/8a386d27295953ee79281fd1f1832e2d/vs_TestAgent.exe -OutFile vs_TestAgent.exe; `
    Start-Process vs_TestAgent.exe -ArgumentList '--quiet', '--norestart', '--nocache' -NoNewWindow -Wait; `
    Remove-Item -Force vs_TestAgent.exe; ` 

# Install VS Build Tools
    Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/12210059/e64d79b40219aea618ce2fe10ebd5f0d/vs_BuildTools.exe -OutFile vs_BuildTools.exe; `
    # Installer won't detect DOTNET_SKIP_FIRST_TIME_EXPERIENCE if ENV is used, must use setx /M
    setx /M DOTNET_SKIP_FIRST_TIME_EXPERIENCE 1; `
    Start-Process vs_BuildTools.exe -ArgumentList '--add', 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.MSBuildTools', '--add', 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetCoreBuildTools', '--add', 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.WebBuildTools;includeRecommended', '--quiet', '--norestart', '--nocache' -NoNewWindow -Wait; `
    Remove-Item -Force vs_buildtools.exe; `
    Remove-Item -Force -Recurse \"${Env:ProgramFiles(x86)}\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\"; `
    Remove-Item -Force -Recurse ${Env:TEMP}\*; `
    Remove-Item -Force -Recurse \"${Env:ProgramData}\Package Cache\"

# Set PATH in one layer to keep image size down.
RUN setx /M PATH $(${Env:PATH} `
    + \";${Env:ProgramFiles}\NuGet\" `
    + \";${Env:ProgramFiles(x86)}\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\TestAgent\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\" `
    + \";${Env:ProgramFiles(x86)}\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\")

# Install Targeting Packs
RUN @('4.0', '4.5.2', '4.6.2', '4.7.2') `
    | %{ `
        Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing https://dotnetbinaries.blob.core.windows.net/referenceassemblies/v${_}.zip -OutFile referenceassemblies.zip; `
        Expand-Archive -Force referenceassemblies.zip -DestinationPath \"${Env:ProgramFiles(x86)}\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\"; `
        Remove-Item -Force referenceassemblies.zip; `
    }
```